# Joomla install database configuration not recognizing MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, installation

I'm trying to get myself up and running with Joomla for the first time, I've installed the full LAMP stack and navigated to my joomla install by going to the local host in my browser 127.0.0.1/joomla.

Joomla install screen displays good.
I am able to successfully get past first install screen "Configuration"

Problem appears in second screen "Database Configuration"

The "Database Type*" combo box has no options, just "None". MySQL is installed on the machine and the service is running, so why would this be?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319211/joomla-installation-database-type-not-showing-in-drop-down-selection-box

Comment: @johnny_s Yeah that was the first thing I found in my search for answers to my issue, and none of those answers solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I've found:
I ran both of these installs (the first was already installed for me, so the second one must have been what is missing)

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```