# Joomla 4.3.1 Web installer fails to find MariaDB (MySQL) or PostGreSQL 11

Tags: joomla-4.x, mysql, postgresql

I am trying to install Joomla 4.3.1 on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.  I am running Apache 2.4.57, PHP 7.4 (for Apache, apparently), PHP 8.2 is also installed, and two installations of PostGreSQL: 10.4 (port 5432) and 11 (port 5433).  I have also installed MariaDB and configured a database and user for Joomla.

When I get to the point in the Joomla web installer where I configure the database, the dropdown select shows only PostGreSQL, and when I get to the point of completing the DB configuration, the installer tells me that I need PostGreSQL 11 not 10.4.  There is no way to tell it to look on port 5433 for PostGreSQL 11, and there is no way to tell it that MariaDB is available and configured as a stand-in for MySQL.

I have installed the package php-mysql (as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319211/joomla-installation-database-type-not-showing-in-drop-down-selection-box and here:
[Joomla install database configuration not recognizing MySQL](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16506/joomla-install-database-configuration-not-recognizing-mysql)).  These specific packages are also installed: php7.4-mysql and php8.2-mysql.

Comment: I've got 3 joomla web sites home hosted on an old laptop using Linux mint. I don't use MariaDB. Happy to share specs or any config info if that will help. It took me a while and probably not optimum but works ok for me. Just tried it as a wee side hobby.
Cheers, good luck, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown lists drivers supported by Joomla that are available on your PHP installation. Availability is generally determined by enabled PHP extensions. To use MySQL databases you need `pdo_mysql` or `mysqli` extension and to use PostgreSQL you need `pdo_pgsql` or `pgsql` extension.

Joomla is not aware of any database servers before connecting. You have to specify the server, including the port, you want it to connect to. E.g. to connect to a local server running on 5433 port, use `localhost:5433`.